# Can't seem to impersonate user or not getting token with google oauth2 in python using a service account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

Very new to the Google API and Python but have had some success with some small actions like getting files under google drive with my own creds etc

I am a Google Workspace admin, I have granted domain-wide delegation to the service account with the full access drive scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
[domain-wide delegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9mbt.png)

The scope is also granted under the oauth consent screen for the same scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
[oauth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkHaj.png)

I also added them in the right order as that can be an issue sometimes apparently on researching this all

The issue I am having is I am wanting to impersonate a user to get a list of their files for an ongoing project and after lots of battling on I am now not getting any errors but don't seem to be impersonating the user correctly and/or not getting a token perhaps?

This could be me being a noob still at this but don't understand why I can't seem to impersonate a user and see their files still using the code below.

I have trawled through my posts on here with people asking similiar questions but not really found an answer yet I'm afraid so wanted to ask this now.

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2 import service_account


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('serviceaccount.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
delegated_credentials = scoped_credentials.with_subject('someone@company.com')

print(delegated_credentials.token)

drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = delegated_credentials)
drive.files().list().execute()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output I am getting is:

```
python.exe .\impersonate.py
None
```

So no errors, but I'm also not getting the expected results of perhaps seeing a token (if that's how it's supposed to work), and at least I thought I'd be now seeing the files and folders of the user in the subject I had specified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so not too long after I posted this I saw something else I thought I should try in the code and it's worked!

A little embarrassing but this may help someone else in the future with this issue :)

The fix for me was adding : delegated_credentials.refresh(Request())

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('serviceaccount.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
delegated_credentials = scoped_credentials.with_subject('someone@company.com')
delegated_credentials.refresh(Request())
print(delegated_credentials.token)
```

I am now able to see the users files and folders successfully